# how can i put 2 or more data for a box gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i am creating feedback page for my website, i am using gridview for showing list of feedback. in a row of gridview i want to fill with photo, date, and username in a box. i did put photo on the box. but i wonder how to put another data

the view:

```
[   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img($data->imageurl,['id'=>'photo']); },
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 10px; max-height: 10px'],
        ],
```

the feedback property from the model / feedback entity:

```
 * @property integer $ID_KOMENTAR
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $KOMENTAR //comment
 * @property string $TANGGAL  //date
 * @property User $iduser     //related to the user
```

and the related of feedback and user.
feedback has one username, username has many feedback

```
public function getIduser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
}
```

the user entity : iduser, username, photo

Comment: What do you mean? The function for value can return any html code you want. Html::img() returns a html string. You can append any other html there. Btw. shouldn't the format be 'raw'? Afaik 'html' would be escaped...

Answer (score 2):

I have made same thing in Yii 1.Hope it can help you. You can customize any column and can put any html there. I will give you a small example for this :)

In the view file you write cgridview code. I am calling a function for getting value for a column and in that function you can create your code accordingly. In my example column name is **Office Managers** and function name is **getManagerListFromOfficeBranch**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'id' => 'user-grid',        
        'columns'=>array(
         array(                    
                    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                    'name',              
                    'email',
                 array(
                     'name'=>'Office Managers',  
                     'type'=>'raw', //for allowing raw html
                     'value'=>'customFunctions::getManagerListFromOfficeBranch($data->officeid)' //here I have created custom function that will get managers of office branch from office table ($data is used to get any value from current row of branch{you can send your feedback id here if you want any info from feedback toggle}only use if you want to )
                     ),
                   ),

    ),

)); ?>
```

Now write you function in a file.
You can create a folder in protected folder with name includes and keep this file in includes folder
**Path Exm: /protected/includes/customFunctions.php**

Include the file in config/main.php

```
Exm: require_once realpath(__DIR__ . ‘/../includes/customFunctions.php’);
```

Function

```
<?php

class customFunctions{

     public static function getManagerListFromOfficeBranch($officeid) {   
        $managerDetails=Office::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('officeid'=> $officeid));  //Office is the model object of Office Table       
        $managerList='';
        foreach ($managerDetails as $key => $value) {
            $managerList=$managerList.$value->manager->first_name." ".$value->manager->last_name."<br/>";
        }
        echo $managerList;        //all managers echo line by line in the column
     echo CHtml::link('Users',array('Users/action')); //write custom HTML Here 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but this shuld work for you

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => Feedback::find()->with('iduser')->orderBy(['ID' => SORT_ASC, 'TANGGAL' => SORT_ASC])]);
    return $this->render('index', [ 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ]);
}
```

in your view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',

        // user attributes examples
        [   
            'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'value' => function($model)
            { 
                return Html::img($model->iduser->imageurl,['id'=>'photo']); 
            },
            'contentOptions' => [
                'style' => 'max-width: 10px; max-height: 10px'
            ],                      
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        // or in this mode
        [   
            'value' => 'iduser.username'
        ],
        ...................

        // your feedback attributes 

        'KOMENTAR',
        'TANGGAL',  

        // actions colum
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Hope this is what you need